# WordPress 4.5.3 and Visual Editor Not Displaying

Tags: wordpress

We have a new multi-site WP install and for some reason on creating/editing posts, we are not seeing the default Visual Editor, as seen below.

[image: Visual Editor screenshot]

Instead we see this, with a sub-set of the features:

[image: What I am seeing screenshot]

We are using the default theme with no changes, no errors in the console, and stopping all other plugins makes no difference. We've also ensured that the user account (admin) does not have the Visual Editor disabled. Anyone else seen this before and or have recommendations on (re)enabling the default Visual Editor?

Comment: You have probably tried this, but try disabling every plugin and setting your theme back to a default theme to rule out any of those issues. There is also a profile option that says something like "disable the visual editor". I'd double check to make sure that isn't on. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: @Ivan As stated in the question, we are using the default theme with no others installed and no changes. And we have disabled all other plugins. The 'disable visual editor' option is not checked.

Comment: Probably there's some JavaScript error which causes the problem. Open the browser developer tools and check the console, you should see some error messages in red.

Comment: @ArturoO - again, as I mention in the question, there are no errors in the console

Comment: Is it happening on all of the multisites or a specific one? Is there anything in the debug log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabling plugins, directly querying the database to review user `rich_editor` settings, and injecting debugging code into the WP PHP source to trace the business logic around the Visual Editor's display, we deduced that this was due to the `User-Agent` header and caching (we have WP deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk behind CloudFront).

[Allowing the User-Agent to pass through](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html), essentially, resolved the issue as WP could then access the data and determine whether or not the Visual Editor should be displayed.

For reference (on WP 4.5.x), the business logic around Visual Editor display is done in `user_can_richedit()` function of the following file:

`wp-includes/general-template.php`

Answer (score 0):

Did some searching, if you're running an Apache server try commenting these lines out of your .htaccess file.

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %2d|- [NC]
RewriteRule .? – [F,L]`

Here is a link to where I found this solution.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-not-showing-in-wp-multisite-install-after-upgrade-to-41/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately our install does not have these lines.

Comment: Is this true for every post type? Have you tried putting Wordpress into debug mode and checking for PHP errors? define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );